# How can I use a Run Parameter in a Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow

I am trying to use this seemingly simple pattern in my Jenkinsfile:

```
def params = input message: 'Define versions to use:', parameters: [
    [
        $class: 'RunParameterDefinition',
        description: '',
        filter: 'SUCCESSFUL',
        name: 'pr1_run',
        projectName: 'MyProject1'
    ], [
        $class: 'RunParameterDefinition',
        description: '',
        filter: 'SUCCESSFUL',
        name: 'pr2_run',
        projectName: 'MyProject2'
    ]
]

// ...
step([
    $class: 'CopyArtifact',
    fingerprintArtifacts: true,
    projectName: 'MyProject1', // resorted to this
    selector: [
        $class: 'ParameterizedBuildSelector',
        parameterName: '${params.pr1_run}'
    ],
    target: _dir
])
```

With the above, I get

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun
```

I've also tried `SpecificBuildSelector`:

```
step([
    $class: 'CopyArtifact',
    fingerprintArtifacts: true,
    projectName: 'MyProject1',
    selector: [
        $class: 'SpecificBuildSelector',
        buildNumber: params.pr1_run.number
    ],
    target: 'pr1'
])
```

and I get

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use field hudson.model.Run number
```

I just want to combine a number of user-chosen upstream project builds to a final build.

Answer (score 1):

Well, Script Security Plugin 1.18.1 and still getting  `org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use method hudson.model.Run getNumber`.

What works is

```
def pr1_number = (''+params.pr1_run).split('#')[1]
```

and then explicitely setting `param = null` and using `pr1_number` in CopyArtifact.

Which just shows that the Pipeline stuff is not quite ready for any inter-project action.

Answer (score 0):

Both problems are symptoms of the same issue, that `RunParameterValue.getValue()` returns a live `Run` object, whereas `getNumber()`—or, more generally, `buildEnvironment`—would be more appropriate from Pipeline. I filed [JENKINS-34101](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-34101) to track this.

If you managed to bypass the `NotSerializableException` (perhaps just lucky), the `RejectedAccessException` is trivially solved by approving that method¹ as an administrator. You should always use `SpecificBuildSelector` with Pipeline (cf. [JENKINS-33577](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33577)).

¹Update the *Script Security* plugin so you are asked to approve `method hudson.model.Run getNumber()`, not `field hudson.model.Run number`.

Comment: Don't understand how I can do ¹. In any case, I would think ideally one wouldn't need to use a build selector but just `step([ $class: 'CopyArtifact', fingerprintArtifacts: true, run: pr1_run ])`. Because why specify the project name twice if I have an object in hand whic perfectly describes the exact run I want.

Comment: (a) Update the _Script Security_ plugin to 1.18 or newer. (b) You need not specify the project name twice if you keep it in a local variable. (c) As described above, because `Run`s are not `Serializable`, so you cannot hang on to references to them. You are better off dealing with flat data like the build number.

Comment: Updating Script Security plugin doesn't help here (as of 1.27, at least).